# cual es la manera correcta de sumar o restar valores de una columna dataframes por condicional?

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo dos `DataFrame` y quiero hacer algo asi .. "si `'stock'` de df2 es mayor al `'stock'` de df1, restar, else sumar. El problema es que cuando hago la condición.. la respuesta puede ser `True` o `False` y nose como tomar solo los `True` y operar, y de la misma manera con los `False`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_producto':['111','222','333','444','555'],
              'stock':[10,100,3,40,50],
                  'version':[1,1,1,1,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_producto':['111','222','333','444','555'],
              'stock':[50,10,30,41,49],
                  'version':[2,2,2,2,2]})

#esto es lo que quisiera hacer, pero me arroja error 

if df2['stock'] > df1['stock']:
    print(df2['stock']-df1['stock'])
else:
    df1['stock'] + df2['stock']
```

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Se agradece de antemano cualquier ayuda,
saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción más eficiente en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución en principio para este caso que la planteada por @PatricioMoracho es usar directamente [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), aunque puede ser bastante menos legible si tenemos más de una condición:

```
df1["nuevo_stock"] = np.where(df2['stock'] > df1['stock'],
                              df2['stock'] - df1['stock'],
                              df1['stock'] + df2['stock']
                              )
```

El primer argumento es la condición, el segundo es el valor a tomar si la condición es verdadera, el tercero el valor a tomar si es falsa.

Tiempos de ejecución para un DataFrame como el del ejemplo pero con 50000 filas:

> **`np.where`**     -> 936 µs ± 6.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7
>   runs, 1000 loops each)
>   **Doble `df.loc`** -> 7.93 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

En cuanto al error que tienes:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Mirate:

- [¿Cómo asigno valores a una variable de un df que depende de un condicional con datos de otro df?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/280235/15089)

la línea:

```
if df2['stock'] > df1['stock']:
```

evalúa  primero `df2['stock'] > df1['stock']`, lo cual es una operación vectorizada (**por cada fila** se evalúa si `stock` en `df2` es mayor que su homólogo en `df1`) que retorna una serie de boleanos. Después el intérprete evalúa si la serie boleana en su conjunto es o no considerada verdadera (`bool(f2['stock'] > df1['stock'])`) lo cual retorna la excepción comentada.

Aunque en Python por norma general un iterable no vacío se evalúa como verdadero, en NumPy/Pandas esto no es así porque están pensados para operar vectorialmente, por lo que lanzan una excepción:

> ```
> >>> bool([])
> False
>
> >>> bool([True, False, True])
> True
>
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> bool(np.array([True, False, True]))
> Exception has occurred: ValueError
>   The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
> ```

En el caso de la lista Python no evalúa lo que contiene, solo mira si tiene algún elemento o no, es decir `bool([False])` es `True` también.

Answer (score 5):

Si no tienes problema en crear una nueva columna, por ejemplo en `df1` podrías hacer:

```
df1.loc[df2.stock >  df1.stock, "nuevo_stock"] = df2.stock - df1.stock
df1.loc[df2.stock <= df1.stock, "nuevo_stock"] = df1.stock + df2.stock

print(df1)

  id_producto  stock  version  nuevo_stock
0         111     10        1         40.0
1         222    100        1        110.0
2         333      3        1         27.0
3         444     40        1          1.0
4         555     50        1         99.0
```

En este caso, usamos [`loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) y dos llamadas, con cada filtro de selección `df2.stock >  df1.stock` y `df2.stock <= df1.stock`